# Executing Variable With Space In Path

Tags: batch-file

So this seems to work:

```
@echo off  
setlocal enabledelayedexpansion  
set currcd=C:\Program Files\script  
echo !currcd!  
"%currcd%\apps\win64\grep.exe"
```

And this works as well:

```
 @echo off  
 setlocal enabledelayedexpansion  
 set currcd=C:\Program Files\script  
 echo !currcd!  
 "%currcd%\apps\win64\win\system32\wmic.exe"
```

And finally, this works (from command line):

```
wmic nicconfig
```

But this does not work:

```
@echo off  
setlocal enabledelayedexpansion  
set currcd=C:\Program Files\script  
echo !currcd!  
"%currcd%\apps\win64\win\system32\wmic.exe" nicconfig
```

Any reason why?

I get this as output:

C:\Program Files\script>test.bat
C:\Program Files\script
Files\script\apps\win64\win\system32\wmic.exe"  nicconfig - Alias not found.

Thank you.

Comment: Are you sure that "nicconfig" has been setup as an alias? Make sure that ENV variable is set, I would think that would fix the issue

Comment: wmic /? yields the following (omitted other output for brevity):   NICCONFIG - Network adapter management.  Since I can run the command from command line, the question is why I cannot do the same within the batch script.

Comment: Looks like this has less to do about scripting and more about how WMIC runs.  Such that if I run wmic as: "C:\Program Files\script\apps\win64\win\System32\WMIC.exe" <any alias>, I get the same error.  Anyone know how to get this to work from command line or otherwise?

Comment: At a command prompt, can you use the command `wmic nicconfig`?

Comment: Yes, that command works from command line.  However, since I am writing an incident response tool, I cannot trust the state of built-in Windows commands.  Thus I was moving it to a directory in "Program Files".  For the time being I have moved it to a directory without a space in the path and it works fine.  I just cannot seem to get it to run in a directory with a space in the path.